# Single Page Applications with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I starting working with Angular in the last few days
and thought that a good starting off project would be to build a
basic single page application. I wanted to discuss the best way
of doing this, as I will eventually be using the concept to build
a very big project.

I am having a hard time understanding the relation between pages
(url locations) and modules (reusable blocks with related controllers)
on the page.

The way I wanted to do it was have the routing block define pages, e.g.

```
var myWebsite = angular.module('myWebsite', ['ngRoute']);

myWebsite.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    }).
    when('/page2', {
        templateUrl: 'page2.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

This block would be in it's own config.js file.

I then wanted to have controllers relating to partials that could be reused on any of the pages.

So let's say we wanted to have menu module which would appear on home and page2.

I wanted this in it's own file, somewhat like this:

```
<div ng-controller="navMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>...
    </ul>
</div>
```

This would then mean I could write my pages home, page2 and whatever other pages in the following style:

```
<ng-include src="/app/modules/menu.html"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="/app/modules/somethingElse.html"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="/app/modules/anotherThing.html"></ng-include>
```

and my index.html body as:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

When doing this I ran into the issue that the controllers could not be dynamically loaded.
I would basically have to list out all possible controllers that would be used in one big file.
This obviously defeats one of the main points of using Angular.

So my feeling is that I've misunderstood Angular and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I want to have small blocks of reusable html, each with their own specific controller, which can be dynamically loaded.

Other tutorials I have seen seem to give each page a controller in the routing config, but with a lot of shared functionality between pages that seems somewhat redundant?

Any help, links, ideas very much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: "I want to have small blocks of reusable html, each with their own specific controller" Look into directives. That's exactly what they're for. I'm not sure what you mean by "which can be dynamically loaded"

Comment: I basically didn't want to have to list out all my controllers in one big file. I wanted to have seperate js files for each partial which would be loaded when needed. Looking into it, this may be outside of angular (I know it can be done with require) in which case I just want to know if my current plan is at least sensible.

Comment: Have you considered using GruntJS to compile your many files into the 'one big file'?  This will allow you to organize your source code however you like but enjoy the benefits of minification and reducing the number of requests the client browser will have to make in order to load your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly then your ng-include(d) discrete chunks of functionality look like ideal candidates for implementing as directives.

Your route provider config would allow you to load the same controller for multiple pages by specifying the controller parameter in the object passed in with the templateUrl parameter. This allows you to share the same controller accross multiple partials and makes your pages composable in so far as you can mix and match partials with controllers depending on which route you're serving. This does mean however, as you have observed, that your controller scripts need to be loaded at startup ie not dynamically but this is the default/standard architecture approach for angular solutions. If you want to load your controllers dynamically then you need to do a little extra work as Dan Wahlin shows in his article here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs